# How can I support different screen sizes with different stylesheets in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, stylesheet, angular5

I am using Angular 5 and I am currently making a header, when I resize the screen to mobile resolution the design becomes very ugly. My idea was making two different stylesheets, one for mobile and one for PC like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" />
```

Is this a smart way to resolve the issue? If not, please give me an alternative.

Besides this, where do I put the stylesheet link in Angular? Normally it is put in the index.html but in Angular styles are listed in the component.ts file, here i can not do ***the media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)"*** part, so again, how can i resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772691/angular2-2-4-3-and-responsive-web-design-using-media-queries-seem-not-to-work ?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, that explains how to place the stylesheets, but my other question, is this a efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: That's not an on-topic question for Stack Overflow, because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne not necessarily, if my way is just a huge workaround, it is not efficient.

Comment: Agreed with @Mike - in my experience, the "standard" way is to use media queries to conditionally load styles based on screen size, and to just include your media queries into your core stylesheet.

Comment: @Mike I have added an answer, please comment if something is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.angular-cli.json` file you should add a string to `apps.styles` array.

For example when your `mobile.css` and `tablet.css` resides inside the `app` folder just add: `mobile.css` and `tablet.css`. 
When the styles reside inside for example a `styles` folder (inside `app`), add: `styles/yourstyle.css`

Corresponding to your css file you add the media queries.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

You don't need to add the style links inside the `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks! And do I put the @media part in the .angular-cli.json as well?

Comment: You should put them inside the stylesheet. Please read the following MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), more specifically over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Targeting_media_features), second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you want to load only the needed css for mobile instead of loading all of it ( desktop one too ) , right ?
If it is so , you have to define a script in your index.html

```
<script>
    var deviceWidth = window.orientation == 0 ? window.screen.width : window.screen.height;
    //use this if you want to check it is really a mobile device.
    var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0 && window.devicePixelRatio;

    var cssHref = deviceWidth > 800 ? "app_desktop.css" : "app_mobile.css";
    var linkElement = document.createElement("link");
    linkElement.setAttribute("rel",  "stylesheet");
    linkElement.setAttribute("type",  "text/css");
    linkElement.setAttribute("href",  cssHref);
<script>
```

This wont be responsive it will work only once . It is also not tested so it wont work as expected :)